# Count and assign categories based on majority voting

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe in the below format:

```
 Class   Category
 XYZ     ABC
 XYZ     ABC
 XYZ     DEF
 XYZ1    ABC
 XYZ1    ABC
 XYZ1    ABC
 XYZ1    HLR
 XYZ2    ABC
```

For every unique class, if there are duplicates, based on "majority voting", I assign the corresponding category to that class. For example, for "XYZ", Category should be "ABC". For "XYZ1", category has to be "ABC" as well as "HLR" appears only once. If there are no discrepencies, then its straightforward (for "XYZ2", it would be "ABC").

Wondering is there a way to achieve this without storing the value counts in  a table and then loop over it to groupby and assign categories based on majority voting.

Any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Try Via `mode`:

```
from statistics import mode
df['New_Categroy'] = df.groupby('Class').transform(mode)
```

###### OUTPUT:

```
  Class Category New_Categroy
0   XYZ      ABC          ABC
1   XYZ      ABC          ABC
2   XYZ      DEF          ABC
3  XYZ1      ABC          ABC
4  XYZ1      ABC          ABC
5  XYZ1      ABC          ABC
6  XYZ1      HLR          ABC
7  XYZ2      ABC          ABC
```

Answer (score 2):

After grouping by class (`groupby`), you have two choices: extract the majority category for each class (apply) or set the majority category to each row (transform).

```
>>> df.groupby('Class')['Category'] \
      .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().idxmax())
Class
XYZ     ABC
XYZ1    ABC
XYZ2    ABC
Name: Category, dtype: object

>>> df.groupby('Class')['Category'] \
      .transform(lambda x: x.value_counts().idxmax())
0    ABC
1    ABC
2    ABC
3    ABC
4    ABC
5    ABC
6    ABC
7    ABC
Name: Category, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting − normally the most common value is `.mode()` but that seems not to exist on groupbys in pandas. We can work around this with `value_counts()`:

```
>>> df.groupby('Class')['Category'].value_counts()
Class  Category
XYZ    ABC         2
       DEF         1
XYZ1   ABC         3
       HLR         1
XYZ2   ABC         1
Name: Category, dtype: int64
```

So we can simply do:

```
>>> df.groupby('Class')['Category'].agg(lambda s: s.value_counts().index[0])
Class
XYZ     ABC
XYZ1    ABC
XYZ2    ABC
Name: Category, dtype: object
```

Or with `transform` to keep the original shape:

```
>>> df.groupby('Class')['Category'].transform(lambda s: s.value_counts().index[0])
0    ABC
1    ABC
2    ABC
3    ABC
4    ABC
5    ABC
6    ABC
7    ABC
Name: Category, dtype: object
```

Note that `value_counts` are sorted by default, so no need for `idxmax()`

---

We can also fallback on `pd.Series.mode()`, but it returns a series due to the risk of ties:

```
>>> df.groupby('Class')['Category'].agg(pd.Series.mode)
Class
XYZ     ABC
XYZ1    ABC
XYZ2    ABC
Name: Category, dtype: object
>>> df.groupby('Class')['Category'].transform(lambda s: s.mode().iloc[0])
0    ABC
1    ABC
2    ABC
3    ABC
4    ABC
5    ABC
6    ABC
7    ABC
Name: Category, dtype: object
```